# Discord.py Adding emoji to reaction doesn't work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I read the documents and I could not find anything useful. Here's my code:

I want to add the :star_struck: emoji to a reaction (The default one in discord)
I looked up the UNICODE on this website: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

```
if "clan" in message.content.lower():
    emoji = '\N{STAR-STRUCK}'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

It says: Unicode error: Unicodeescape can't decode.....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the codepoint (`\U0001f929`) or the unicode ()

```py
await message.add_reaction("\U0001f929")
```

```py
await message.add_reaction("")
```

*To get the unicode simply `\:emoji:` in discord, send it and copy*

After a bit of research I found out that it's not called `STAR STRUCK`, it's only the name discord gave it, the proper name is `GRINNING FACE WITH STAR EYES`

```py
await message.add_reaction("\N{GRINNING FACE WITH STAR EYES}")
```

Comment: sometimes just `await message.add_reaction("")` doesn't work, if it not work I convert the emoji to string first like this: `await message.add_reaction(str(""))`